# What are the hero leveling path to get through the hero "walls"?

Tags: tap-titans

In tap titans, I understand a "wall" as when your total DPS begins to fall short of monster health (so it takes too long to kill monsters).

It usually is a gear check to halt the progress before you can hire one of the more advanced heroes (flavius, chester, mohacas, pixie, dark lord, *et alia*).

To overcome the walls, you have to usually level up the highest up hero, and evolve another hero.

So, what hero levels should I get to try and overcome these walls:

- Chester
- Mohacas
- Jaqlin
- Pixie
- Jacklope
- Dark Lord

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is very opinionated since coming over a wall as you say can be done in many diffrent ways depending on how you play the game, since tap titans is a mobile game most people dont like to put to much time into play and depend on the money they get from "afk" farming while i would say the fastest and most effective way to get past these walls is to evolve since it lets you get to the level where you were rather quickly instead of the long grind to level one character. Once you get to the level in which you had this wall it will probably be very easy for you to surpass since you now have a DMG boost and such.